# Filtering rows based on a complex condition in a dataframe with spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have to filter rows from a dataframe based on some conditions input by a user. I read a csv file to get each condition as a string. Then use the code below to do the filtering.

`dataframe.filter(expr(condition))`

This works for simple conditions that do not contain '&', '|'. Ex: "col1 != 0", "col2 > 2".

Now the requirement is to make it work for complex conditions as well.

Following is an example

dataframe

`col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
-----+------+------+------
1.0  | 10   | 100  |    x 
0.2  | 20   | 200  |    y 
1.3  | 30   | 300  |    x`

complex condition: "(col1 < 1.0) & (col2 + col3) >= 200) & (col4 != 'x')"

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform `&` and `|` into `and` and `or`. If the complex condition is deeply nested, you can just do it recursively.

Here is the list of Spark SQL functions for your reference:

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html